# como habilitar un boton,con IsEnabled desactivado

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy utilizando visual studio 2017, probé con IsEnabled pero no me vuelve a habilitar el botón que necesito, que me habilite y pueda ser utilizado con el WPF

```
  private void CboTipoVehiculo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CBOselectorVeh.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            btnAgregar.IsEnabled = IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La propieda IsEnabled solo acepta valores booleanos.
Tu codigo no tiene sentido

```
btnAgregar.IsEnabled = IsEnabled = true;
```

Si lo que quieres es que se habilite el boton segun X evento te sugiero que pruebes esto:

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 // Un ejemplo rapido. El siguiente evento del TextBox habilitara o deshabilitara el boton si hay texto o no (Simulando un boton login)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length==0)
            button1.IsEnabled = false;
        else
            button1.IsEnabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: pero no necesito que sea llenando datos de un textbox, lo que necesito es que el ComboBox con la opcion 1 que en caso seria Automóvil, (porcierto utilizo un enum con los datos para mi combobox), con la opcion 0 defini que sea "SinInformacion" y no me soluciona el tema de volver a habilitar (siendo que cuando parte mi WPF lo desabilita, por las opciones de mi combobox)

Answer (score 0):

El index de los combobox va desde 0 a n, pero por defecto el index es -1 (a menos que al llenarlo de item le digas que su selectedIndex es 0), por lo tanto si seleccionas el primer item, el index que seleccionaste es 0.

```
private void CboTipoVehiculo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    btnAgregar.IsEnabled = (CBOselectorVeh.SelectedIndex == 0); //true:false
}
```

Si quieres que se habilite con cualquier item que selecciones siempre que sea un item válido y no el que muestra por default el combobox (el nulo -1)

```
private void CboTipoVehiculo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    btnAgregar.IsEnabled = (CBOselectorVeh.SelectedIndex > -1);//true:false
}
```

Solo me queda una duda que estás controlando el evento del Combobox **CboTipoVehiculo**, pero estás validando el SelectedIndex de **CBOselectorVeh**, eso me causa extrañeza.

Un saludo.

Comment: necesito que con primera opción me vuelva habilitar el botón, con la 0 deje por defecto que no la habilite, como inicie el programa con las opciones del botón y le desabilite el "IsEnabled"

Comment: A partir del ejemplo que te ha compartido @Leodev es tan simple como poner un if controlando el valor actual de SelectedIndex en el evento SelectionChanged

Answer (score -1):

Con setear **btnAgregar.IsEnabled**, debiera ser suficiente para habilitar el botón. Por lo tanto la causa debe ser otra.

1- ¿Comprobaste con el debugger que la sentencia:

```
btnAgregar.IsEnabled = IsEnabled = true;
```

se está ejecutando?

2- Verifica con el debugger el estado final del atributo **IsEnabled** del botón, (luego de ser supuetamente habilitado). Lo más seguro es que esté en false.

3- Si la respuesta a **1)** es un si, entonces alguna otra línea de código lo está volviendo a deshabilitar más adelante. Revisa.

Comment: si lo desabilite con las opciones del botón, eso necesito que cuando cambie a las opcion 1 de combobox, lo vuelva a habilitar